# What is the the command to add an application in startup applications preferences?

Tags: 20.04, startup

I want to open `slack` when startup. What will the command need to set in startup applications preferences?

How to get the right command when setting any other application (e.g skype, vscode, firefox etc) in startup?

[Edit]
There is a `browse` button in the command input. In which directory can i browse to find that application start command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy (delete) the application's .desktop file to (from) ~/.config/autostart/

The .desktop files are usually located at /usr/share/applications, but you can create a custom one if you want.

For more info, check out:

http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-0.5.html
and
http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Example:
~/.config/autostart/oneko.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=oneko
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=oneko
Name=oneko
Comment[en_US]=The cat
Comment=The cat
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't very clear. Here's what I think you need. Open up the startup applications app. Go to the right pane and click add. Enter the name of the app as `slack`. The command as slack and click add. It will now start-up whenever you log in.

Comment: How to find that command? How can i find the right command for any other application (e.g vscode, firefox etc)?

Comment: Its code for vscode, its firefox for firefox. You'll have to experiment with that on your command line, there's no pre-defined format.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If yes, please vote the answer

Comment: There is a browse button in the command input. In which directory can i browse to find that application start command?

Comment: uhhmm, you don't need to do that. Next to browse there is a text box. Just type in 'slack' and that's it.